# How to show up map annotations while zooming in?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a map with a lot of annotations, which are pinned on whole country. Now I would like to show annotation automatically, when somebody zooming in the map. Do you have any idea how to start with it? Now I have a few lines of code:

> Annotation Class

```
class myAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation{

var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title: String, subtitle: String, coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinates
} 
} // end of class
```

> MapView Class

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

/* OUTLETS */    

@IBOutlet weak var mapOutlet: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

/* VARIABLES */

let lm = CLLocationManager()
var data = [[String:String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // pin's data is loaded from the server and added to `data`

} 

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         self.addAnnotationToTheMap()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func addAnnotationToTheMap(){

    for i in data{

        let latitude = Double(i["latitude"]!)
        let longtitude = Double(i["longitude"]!)

        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longtitude!)

        let pinOnTheMap = myAnnotation(title: i["title"]!, subtitle: i["subtitle"]!, coordinates: coordinates)
        mapOutlet.addAnnotation(pinOnTheMap)
    }    
}
} // end of class
```

any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can select programmatically any annotation, or annotation which is closer to the center of the map, by calling `mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated:true)`. But only one annotation could be selected at one time.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
extension  Double{

    func between( a:Double, b:Double) -> Bool{
        if self > a && self < b{
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}


extension MapViewController : MKMapViewDelegate{

    //using special image for standard view for the annotation
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("wtg")
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "wtg")
            anView!.canShowCallout = true
            anView!.image = UIImage(named: "wtg")
        }
        else {
            anView!.annotation = annotation
        } 
        return anView
    }

    //if the region center is close to something, show the annotations
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        let region = mapView.region
        if region.center.latitude.between(myLatA, b: mylatB) && region.center.longitude.between(myLonA, b: myLonB)
        {
            //Add extra anotations or do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Apple has quite good [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) on this subject. You should look at the "Displaying Multiple Annotation Objects" section and also use the delegate methods  mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated: and mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:Methods.